# WordPress Pagination/Infinite Scroll breaking another plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, infinite-scroll

I've implemented infinite scroll on a site I'm developing using WordPress, the Thesis theme, and the plugin Infinite Scroll v2.6.2 by Beaver6813 et al.

Unfortunately, it seems to breaking another plugin, kk Star Ratings v2.6 by Kamal Khan.

My site is configured to display posts with a certain category on the home page via Settings > Reading > Your Latest Posts and the following code in my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if (    $q->is_home()
         && $q->is_main_query()
    ) {
        $q->set( 'category_name',  'strip' );
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 ); 
    }
});
```

Infinite scrolling is working. The star ratings plugin displays as I want it to between the post title and post content.

However, the core functionality -- the ability to click on a star and rate the post -- only works on the initial load of three posts. Everything lazy-loaded after that displays the stars and the number of ratings, but I can't actually click a star to rate the post.

Here's an example of it working on one of the top posts: [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIMhu.gif).

And here's an example of the broken functionality: [not-working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzFit.gif).

The difference appears to be in the styling.

The working ones have a width of 80%, as follows:

```
<div class="kksr-fuel kksr-star orange" style="width: 80%;"</div>
```

The broken ones have a width of 0%:

```
<div class="kksr-fuel kksr-star yellow" style="width:0%;"</div>
```

I did try forcing "width: 80% !important" via my stylesheet. While it visually changed the interface, I still wasn't able to save a rating by clicking.

Although I can see the non-working plugins, I'm hypothesizing that the width is essentially hiding the piece of functionality I need in order to rate the posts.

I just can't quite figure out how to tell it to knock it off.

I've tried a few different plugins and had the same results. I'm a novice, but I suspect the way I'm using infinite scroll for pagination is preventing the plugin from fully... I don't know, *loading*, I guess.

I feel like I'm very close to figuring this out... just need a nudge over the finish line, please!

Comment: Got it fixed with the help of someone on Fiverr. We added some JavaScript and enqueued it via functions.php (or custom.php since it's using the Thesis theme).

Here's the code:

'code'
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
  setInterval(function(){ 
    if($('.home .content > div:last-child').hasClass('lg')){
    
    }else{
      $('.home .content > div:last-child').addClass('lg');
      $(".kk-star-ratings").kkstarratings();
      
    }
  
  }, 2000);


}); 
'code'

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix I mentioned earlier in my comment.

The code below was provided by someone from Fiverr. I added it to a script and enqueued it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  setInterval(function(){ 
    if(!$('.home .content > div:last-child').hasClass('lg')){
      $('.home .content > div:last-child').addClass('lg');
      $(".kk-star-ratings").kkstarratings();
    }
  }, 2000);
});
```